# wkhtmltopdf + nodejs error after pipe(res)

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf

i still have a problem with wkhtmltopdf in node js.

I create my html that come from the compiled ejs template.
I create the pdf with the code above and the pdf is perfetct

```
    wkhtmltopdf(html, {
                    pageSize: information.configPdf.pageSize,
                        orientation: information.configPdf.orientation,
                    marginLeft: `${information.configPdf.marginLeft}mm`,
                    marginTop: `${information.configPdf.marginTop}mm`,
                    marginRight: `${information.configPdf.marginLeft}mm`,
                    marginBottom: `${information.configPdf.marginTop}mm`,
                    printMediaType:true
                    }).pipe(res);
```

After this i still have an erorr like this:

```
::1 - - [01/Jun/2021:08:37:32 +0000] "GET /pdfResult?idStored=11&parametriStored=M8 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36"
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Exit with code 1 due to network error: ProtocolUnknownError

wkhtmltopdf exited with code 1
    at handleError (/home/mauro/Documenti/Sviluppo/etichetto-Se/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf/index.js:142:16)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/mauro/Documenti/Sviluppo/etichetto-Se/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf/index.js:114:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at handleError (/home/mauro/Documenti/Sviluppo/etichetto-Se/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf/index.js:156:14)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/mauro/Documenti/Sviluppo/etichetto-Se/node_modules/wkhtmltopdf/index.js:114:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I just some week that i'm fighting against it and i can't resolve.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have an example of the HTML that causes this error when passed to wkhtmltopdf? The error suggests that the HTML makes a request for an external resource (script, style, image, font, etc.) with an invalid URL of some kind, but we would need to see the HTML to be sure.

Comment: The file is so big because there is the autogeneratione of graph and other feature for autocompose pdf from mssql. For jump the problem of including file, that generate a lot of headhacke with the path i generate an array of html pages, compile ejs template server side cycling the array and put the every html content in the pdf page template. I don't have any link outside but wkhtmltopdf crash with that error. If i assign a global var for html-page-array and after i complete to generate single page i try to cycle the array the pdf is empty

Comment: PS i try to insert code but is over char limit